DIsplay ORCID icon instead of ID in LNCS template
In the LNCS document class (llncs) display ORCID ID in authors name, instead of ORCD icon:
\author{First Author\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-1111-2222-3333} \and
Second Author\inst{2,3}\orcidID{1111-2222-3333-4444} \and
Third Author\inst{3}\orcidID{2222--3333-4444-5555}}


NOTE: See the complete code in LNCS Overleaf template.
How do change this to ORCID icon?

?? Which icon ??

\usepackage{orcidlink}  % This package does the trick, put this line in the preamble
\author{First Author\inst{1}\orcidlink{0000-1111-2222-3333} \and
Second Author\inst{2,3}\orcidlink{1111-2222-3333-4444} \and
Third Author\inst{3}\orcidlink{2222--3333-4444-5555}}

Instead of using \orcidID you can simply use the package orcidlink, which does exactly what you want (see below).


I assume you mean the ORCID logo there. This template wants the actual ID there, but if (for your own version) you want the logo there, this should work:
\renewcommand*{\orcidID}[1]{\textsuperscript{\includegraphics[height=2.5ex]{orcid.logo.icon}}}

where the logo is a PDF (or EPS) of the SVG image here: https://orcid.org/assets/vectors/orcid.logo.icon.svg.
I suspect that what you really want is the ORCID logo hyperlinked to the URL that takes you to the number in question. That should be a trivial extension using \href with the argument to the \orcidID command above.
